# Dynamic Collection View Cell with TableView inside?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

i have added a TableView inside Collection View Cell, but the Collection View Cell height should depend on TableView data.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds awfully complicated. What about using a vertical UIStackView instead of that tableview?

Comment: @BartvanKuik can you give me an example in Swift 3 for that?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can be achieved by reloading the tableview first, waiting for it complete, fetch the tableview Content height then load the collectionview giving the cell the right values

```
tableView.reloadData()
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            requiredCellHeight = self.tableView.contentSize.height
        })
```

This waits on the main thread for the tableview to load. Though not an ideal solution as we are blocking the main thread, might work for this complex setup